# How add a function in a condition method in db api

Tags: database

I am strugginling to find out how to execute the below query using drupal's db api

```
$startdate = '1491001200';
$enddate = '1498690799';
"SELECT * FROM field_data_field_symposium_event_time
    WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field_symposium_event_time_value) BETWEEN
    $startdate AND $enddate;"
```

I have tried adding 'addExpression' but does not work. I did it like this

```
$query = db_select('node','n');
$query->join('field_data_field_symposium_event_time', 'et', 'et.entity_id = n.nid');    
$query->condition('et.field_data_field_symposium_event_time_value',array($day_start, $day_end), 'BETWEEN'));
$query->addExpression('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(et.field_symposium_event_time_value)');
$query->fields('et',array('field_symposium_event_time_value'));
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

The `$result` is empty. Is there a way to achieve this  as I dont want to write the full query .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the addExpression is for SELECT clause expressions

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/function/Select%3A%3AaddExpression/8.2.x

For a WHERE clause expression it should be

```
$query->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(et.field_symposium_event_time_value) BETWEEN :start AND :end', array(':start' => $day_start, ':end' => $day_end));
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21QueryConditionTrait.php/function/QueryConditionTrait%3A%3Awhere/8.2.x

And then of course remove your `$query->condition(...);` line.

Comment: Thank you exactly what I needed. I still dont understand the concept of addExpression.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote, but I am wondering if that actually worked.  I suddenly realized that addExpression() is for the SELECT cause, and you can use where() for WHERE clause expressions.  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21QueryConditionTrait.php/function/QueryConditionTrait%3A%3Awhere/8.2.x I will update the answer

Comment: Yea I upvoted too early. This doesn't work on another conditions, would you know to use where.??

Comment: Did you see the updated answer?

Comment: I did, this somehow is not working, although it could be because of the format of `$start_date` and `$end_date`. they are generated like this

`$start_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime(04/05/2017)));`
`$end_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime(10/05/2017)));`
while the `field_symposium_event_time_value` is in `2017-05-05 17:30:00` format.

Comment: If you copied that correctly you are getting wrong dates, because you didn't quote the dates so it's evaluation 4 / 5 / 2007 as a math statement.

Comment: Thanks for until now, the dates are dynamic, I pasted the date directly for ease of reading. the date passed at `strtotime` is like this `strtotime($from_date)`, and `$from_date` is being passed as a string in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: Sorry got interupted try changing `strtotime(04/05/2017)` to `strtotime('04/05/2017')`  Also I think just `strtotime('04/05/2017')` will give you the same result as your $start_date formula and for $end_date doing something like `strtotime('04/05/2017') + ($hours * 60 * 60)` where $hours is how many hours since 00:00 - it might be cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59189/discussion-between-r-leurquin-and-sanjok-gurung).

Answer (score 0):

I think that ->addExpression is about adding SQL snippets like yours to modify selected columns right after the SELECT (vs. adding expressions to a WHERE clause).

The ->where() (and ->having()) clauses are what you want.